Unable to find bluetooth devices using InTheHand.Bluetooth
I'm using MAUI .NET. I want to save all bluetooth devices in range of the device that code runs on to a collection. Here is sample code called after button click.
private async void OnButtonBluetoothClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isBluetoothAvailable = await Bluetooth.GetAvailabilityAsync();
    if (!isBluetoothAvailable)
    {
        await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Bluetooth is unavailable.", "Exit");
        if (Application.Current is null) throw new NullReferenceException();
        Application.Current.Quit();
    }
    else
    {
        lblBluetoothSupport.Text = "Bluetooth available";
    }

    var devices = await Bluetooth.ScanForDevicesAsync(new RequestDeviceOptions { AcceptAllDevices = true });
    lblBluetoothSupport.Text = $"Devices found: {devices.Count}";
    foreach (var device in devices.ToList())
    {
        BluetoothDevices.Add(device);
        Debug.WriteLine($"{device.Name} {device.Id} {device.Gatt}");
    }
}

First part of the code works as expected - if there is no bluetooth enabled, then application is closing. The second part does not work as expected. No matter how many devices with bluetooth enabled are in range, no matter how many devices are directly paired, no matter if application runs on Windows or Android, devices has always zero elements.
It doesn't seem to be permissions issue. Here are Android permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />

And Windows permissions:
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="location"/>

Application needs to run at least on mobile devices, but testing it on Windows is easier, so for now it supports it too.

Based on the words you are using, I would say that you are trying to recognise Bluetooth Classic devices, but the code you are using is for incompatible Bluetooth LE devices.
Are you aware of this difference?

@Risto Yes. It looks like all modern BT devices are BLE. After clearing solution and rebuilding, and adding .ToList() to foreach loop it started to work on Windows, but Android keeps showing that there are 0 devices. My bet would be permission issues, but as you can see permissions are properly assigned in AndroidManifest.

In recent versions of Android, some Bluetooth permissions are runtime permissions and must be granted by the application user.

@Risto it appears it only need BLUETOOTH_SCAN, I have more just in case. Application crashes if I don't go into the settings to give it permissions, but even with them it constantly shows 0.

Since BLUETOOTH_SCAN is a runtime permission, did I understand correctly that you request it at runtime, and even if the authorisation is granted, it does not work?

Scanning and connecting bluetooth also need the Location Permission. I reproduced your problem and fixed it by the following steps:

I intalled the nuget package InTheHand.BluetoothLE version 4.0.37 and copied your code to a new project.
I added the location permission into the AndroidManifest.xml, so the full permission is:

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


I request the permission at runtime. In the MainActivity:

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Bluetooth>();
            Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
        }

Finally, I can get the list of bluetooth devices.
